# Introducing: Compoundoku!

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

[image]

> **Rules of Compoundoku:**
>
> - Solve both left and right Sudokus.
> - In addition, the board below them is the Compound Board of both Sudokus.
> - Each number on the Compound Board should tell either: (1) the number on the left Sudoku, or (2) the sum of both numbers on the left and right Sudokus; in the respective position.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is the answer

> [image]

Partial Reasoning

> For starters the 1 must appear on the left and the 6 must be the sum of both.
>  Once we make a choice of how to split the 6, the rest of the grid is filled in very quickly (4x4 Sudokus are very restrictive). If we put 3 on the left and 3 on the right or 2 on the left and 4 on the right, we can quickly reach a contradiction. However, putting 4 on the left and 2 on the right allows us to complete the grid in a unique way using the logic. A key step is realising that splitting the bottom 4 will eventually produce a contradiction so it must be that a 4 appears in that position on the left.

Comment: This is correct, nicely done!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same answer as hexomino except the right sudoku is

> 3 1 2 4
>  4 2 1 3
>  1 4 3 2
>  2 3 4 1

so I guess there are at least 2 answers.

I like this puzzle idea though!

Comment: This grid fails in the left-most square of the second row. Note that athin's rules say it is either the number of the left sudoku, or the sum, but **not** the number of the right sudoku.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately it doesn't tell the number on the right sudoku. But hey, since this genre is pretty new I may experimenting with allowing the right one later on. Or maybe allowing multiplication also, hmm. Yeah let's see lol.

Comment: oh yeah i misread the instructions